# What is stricter way to match an element using cssSelecter in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 elements on my webpage

element 1 : `<div class="DynarchCalendar-day DynarchCalendar-day-othermonth" dyc-type="date" unselectable="on" dyc-date="19960429">`

element 2  : `<div class="DynarchCalendar-day" dyc-type="date" unselectable="on" dyc-date="19960501">`

If i do

```
List<WebElement> DynarchCalendar_day  = driver.findElements(By
                    .cssSelector("div.DynarchCalendar-day"));
```

I will get list of WebElements containing both element 1 and element 2

If i do

```
List<WebElement> DynarchCalendar_day  = driver.findElements(By
                    .cssSelector("div.DynarchCalendar-day.DynarchCalendar-day-othermonth"));
```

I will get list of WebElements containing only element 1

What can i do to get Element 2 only ?

Comment: Are they right next to each other in the HTML or are they both different in how they sit in the HTML? (for instance, are they children of two *different* `div`'s?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `not` to find divs with `DynarchCalendar-day` but not `DynarchCalendar-day-othermonth`.

The css-selector would be:

```
"div.DynarchCalendar-day:not(.DynarchCalendar-day-othermonth)"
```

Comment: i wondering maybe if you can paste some links which will help me understand css selector better :)

Comment: Can you help me out ? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675848/webdriver-2-0-session-expire-error-for-a-popup-window-if-an-instance-of-ie-ie

Comment: You could start with http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/. After that, I think you just learn the selectors as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:not()`, but it doesn't works in old Internet Explorer(7, 8). 
Also you can use `div[class='DynarchCalendar-day']`. It looks for exact coincidence.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but in my case i didn't want exact match with 'DynarchCalendar-day'