# WebDriver 2.0 : Session expire error for a popup window if an instance of IE (IE8) is already present

Tags: java, session, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate a web application where after clicking a button say 'popup' a new window is launched.

While performing the steps manually I face no issues if multiple windows/tabs(e.g. Google , StackOverflow) are already open.

However if I run the same steps by automation,then after clicking the button 'popup' new window is launched and I get a 'session has expired' alert box.

Please Note : If I close all the instances of IE , then my automation code works fine. I am using Webdriver java API.

What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Do you have more than one test? If so, do you close the previous browser before you start a new one in the next test?  Can you elaborate on exactly what you are doing?  Does getWindowHandles() return size >0 before your tests start?

Comment: 1. I am trying to automate an end to end test case
2. I do not close the previous browser
3. getWindowHandles() return size = 1 even before i use any driver.get("url");


Please note that test works fine if i close all IE instances and run the test.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue today, what worked for me was killing the IE processes before opening the browser. Even though this is super late I hope this helps anyone else.